# How can I remove a 2006 Kohler bathroom faucet with an odd mounting nut?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

This is a 2006 Kohler bath faucet and I want to replace it.

There's a post here with one similar but not the same-the other one has a way to take off from the top, mine does not. Maybe just use pliers and twist the nut even though the plastic is there?

[image: Kohler bath faucet 2006]

Answer (score 3):

Kohler was little help, but I used a Philips screwdriver and it does in-fact twist it off.

You don't need to insert the screwdriver too much into the opening--maybe 1/4 inch.  Just turn counter clockwise and it will push the toggle bolt off from underneath.

[image]

Another picture.  You don't need to insert the screwdriver too much into the opening--maybe 1/4 inch.  [image: Insert Screwdriver]

Comment: Why is the toggle on upside down in this photo? -  Are you saying that a Philips screwdriver turns the threaded rod. Since you posted this as an answer and for others that may need the info, a more detailed description would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you first remove the stopper linkage, then unscrew the toggle nut. The fact that the large washer has two tabs that project down through the toggle nut makes me wonder, but I would go ahead and twist the toggle CCW and see what happens.

Comment: I agree that drain / stopper linkage once removed will allow the handle to be removed and easy access to unscrew the nut ccw as Jim suggested, I have seen that type of assembly on stoppers that have a lever a bit fancier than straight pull but harder to adjust as the throw is limited.+

Comment: OK So Kohler emailed me regarding this long discontinued faucet.  When I did take out the stopper there's  a tiny hole  on the top where I pulled out the stopper actuator, for a phillips screw driver and yes, it loosened the whole faucet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the detail on this. I was going crazy with it. There is no way this can be opened from the bottom. Simply insert a Philips screw driver as shown in the picture and unscrew it until the nut falls down. Toot hardly 30seconds

Comment: This is a duplicate of answers  from above.